# How to resolve the problem in ionic during build creation

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

How to resolve the problem in ionic during build creation

I am getting error when I build ...In ionic.

Answer (score -3):

```
 **Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions** 
You can Also Watch Video here : [https://youtu.be/4aAA1qjLMwY][1]
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

***********************************************/

1) Download JAVA jdk8 (jdk-8u281-windows-x64.exe) From https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

2) Download Gradle-7 From https://gradle.org/install/

Now First Install download jdk on your computer
After that Extract Gradle-7 zip file, copy the extract file and paste in Local Disk(C:)


Steps For Setting Enviroments

1) Open System enviroment of your Pc, Click on Enviroment Variable.
2) Go to User Variable, Click on New
3) Add Variable Name--> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and Variable Value--> **C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**
4) Add One More Variable Name--> JAVA_HOME and Variable Value--> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281
5) After that go to System Variable double click On Path, after that click on NEW and add gradle path C:\gradle-7.0\bin

6) Restart Your Pc.

7) After Pc Open go to your Project Directory
8) Open The terminal and write ionic cordova build android

Now I have Successfully Create APK Without android studio
```